# Are apps that access gmail only have write-only access or full gmail access (potential security risk?)

Tags: api, sms, gmail, backup, android-account

I use a backup app to backup SMS text messages to my GMail account registered on my HTC Desire Z Android 2.3 phone.

The app requests access to the gmail account. But what does this actually mean? Does it mean:

- the application has write-only access to the gmail - i.e. can insert emails but not delete or adjust other existing emails (does the Android API provide for that?)
- the application has full access to the email, and could potentially delete emails if there was a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: this question doesn't seem to belong on Stackoverflow. This site is for asking specific questions about coding problems, not about how some code in some program based on some SDK on some device may or may not work.

If an application can access your Gmail account, as far as I know, this means full control, including deletion.
That doesn't have to mean there is actual code in the program that even tries to delete something, but I guess you're right: coding bugs could probably delete your email.

But that goes for a lot of applications: you trust the developer to test extensively before you rely on him/ her to handle your photos, email, passwords etc with care right? :)

Comment: +1 Accepted. Assuming you've looked at and understand the API (I haven't hence my question) then what you say answers my question. I agree: I want to trust the developer as well. But this does make me concerned that there does not appear to be levels of authorisation as I suggested. I suppose when one installs anything on any platform, it runs the risk of unwanted deliberate abuse. But I would have thought mobile OS developers would have learnt from the malware seen by Windows, particularly given that a phone's more limited connectivity and resources reduce feasibility of anti-malware sw.

Comment: That said, there are mobile internet security apps made by companies established in Desktop security. Perhaps these plug the hole I am suggesting?

Comment: Thanks I've removed direct reference because I love that app and wouldn't want to harm the reputation by associating it with this question of *general* concern.

Comment: EDIT: also removed app name. 
ORIG: as far as I know (with my limited knowledge of the API), there is no API to access Gmail in Android. This is typically achieved via OAuth/ IMAP, via plain Java. Considering that, and the context of your question and the applications you mention (I use that application too by the way), one pretty much has to conclude full access is granted once authorisation is granted to the application... Perhaps this info on Google site helps?